# sql query to find missing records

Tags: sql

I am using a transaction table called Student_Details which contain Batch_No, PF_No, Emp_name,DOB, DOR and DOJ along with other details. There is another master table called Batch_Master which contains Batch_No, From_date, To_date and Due_date.
I want to get the details of staff whose due date is within Enter_date1 and Enter_date2 who actually fall due within this period and such of those staff whose due_date is earlier to Enter_date1 but still not come (i.e there is no record for the same person with a DOJ after due_date.)
Please help in designing a query in MS-Access

Comment: you need to show that you applied at least *some* effort to this. show some code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: You should look specifically at SQL WHERE clause. I think this would be most beneficial for what you are trying to achieve. WHERE is used in these types of conditional statements to say if this is true (or false depending on the situation) then return this. 

For example:


SELECT *

FROM <location>

WHERE Due_date > Enter_date1 AND Due_date < Enter_date2.

Answer (score 0):

You should look specifically at SQL WHERE clause. I think this would be most beneficial for what you are trying to achieve. WHERE is used in these types of conditional statements to say if this is true (or false depending on the situation) then return this.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM <location>
WHERE Due_date > Enter_date1 AND Due_date < Enter_date2.
```

However I am really confused on this statement:

"such of those staff whose due_date is earlier to Enter_date1 but still not come (i.e there is no record for the same person with a DOJ after due_date"

To me this sounds like you just want to return every less than Enter_date2, but you want to ensure that there is only Unique records return... or so I assume.